# CSS/Masonry -> span multiple columns

Tags: html, css, grid, masonry

So I am excited about the new masonry feature native to CSS as of what seems like just a few months ago. I've only found one tutorial that seems to be completely up to date: [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrPz_wmBsAE&t=573s)

This tutorial includes a snippit on using the class `feature` to span 2 columns in the masonry layout.

However. I cannot get his code to work simultaneously with A) the span and B) masonry layout. If I disable the `grid-template-rows: masonry;`, I can get his spans to work. I don't see how he did it. Furthermore, I have copied [his code](https://codepen.io/kevinpowell/pen/yLaYxab) and attempted to run it and had the same problem. I will add that on codepen, his class of `feature` doesn't span 2 columns, either.

Admittedly this is only the second time I've done anything with CSS in 11 years so there's a very good chance I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: this feature is only available on Firefox is you enable a specific flag (related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66457526/8620333) did you enable the flag?

Comment: ~~ack. when he said that in the video I thought to myself, "oh this was months ago, I'm sure the other browsers have it up by now." ~~


I re-read the comment you link. The masonry flag that's available in firefox is only to enable regular masonry. Chrome and Brave browser (my browser) both do this by now. The problem is the span aspect specifically.